# Zur Rechenschaft oder zur Verantwortung ziehen

Tags: difference, word-choice, phrase, synonym

> **zur Rechenschaft ziehen:** jemanden [für etwas] zur Rechenschaft ziehen (jemanden [für etwas] zur Verantwortung ziehen); jn verantwortlich machen
>
> **zur Verantwortung ziehen:** jemanden [für etwas] zur Verantwortung ziehen (jemanden als Schuldige[n] [für etwas] zur Rechenschaft ziehen); jn verantwortlich machen für etwA

Quellen: Duden, http://www.dietz-und-daf.de/GD_DkfA/Gramminfo/txt_MII2/FVG-Liste2.pdf

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Wendungen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beide Wendungen unterscheiden sich nur in Nuancen.

**Zur Rechenschaft ziehen** bedeutet zunächst, dass jemand *Rechenschaft* über sein Handeln *ablegen* soll, also dazu Rede und Antwort stehen und sich rechtfertigen. Es schwingt die Erwartung mit, dass dabei ein Fehlverhalten festgestellt und sanktioniert wird, aber es ist nicht völlig ausgeschlossen, dass die Vorwürfe ausgeräumt werden können. Die Wendung bietet sich aus stilistischen Gründen außerdem immer an, wenn die betroffenen Personen als "die Verantwortlichen" bezeichnet werden.

Beispiele, in denen meiner Meinung nach diese Wendung die bessere Wahl ist als "zur Verantwortung ziehen" (alle gefunden auf *linguee.de*):

> Statt einer nicht hinterfragten herrschenden – anonymen – Macht nimmt die wirtschaftliche Globalisierung Gesichter und
>   Stimmen an, ... die uns dazu aufrufen, verantwortlich
>   zu handeln, und die uns zur Rechenschaft
>   ziehen für unsere Entscheidungen und unser Handeln im alltäglichen Umgang mit der
>   Wirtschaft. [Quelle](http://lwf-assembly2003.org/lwb-vollversammlung/htdocs/lwfimages/D-Studybook-Part3-09.pdf)
>
> Neulich wollte er Vater zur Rechenschaft ziehen, weil wir den Hund auf ein paar Rehböcke gehetzt haben, die auf einem unserer Felder den Weizen fraßen. [Quelle nicht mehr online](http://tapio-de.org/samples/victorswut.pdf)
>
> ... die
>   Verantwortlichen sollten zur Rechenschaft gezogen, Sanktionen sollten ausgesprochen und durchgesetzt werden. [Quelle](http://www.transparency.de/fileadmin/pdfs/Themen/webversion_final.pdf)

**Zur Verantwortung ziehen** betont den Aspekt, dass eine Person oder Organisation *verantwortlich gemacht* wird, also die Konsequenzen einer Handlung oder eines Ereignisses zu tragen hat. Diese Handlung oder dieses Ereignis werden als Tatsache angenommen; es geht nicht darum, diese noch zu diskutieren.

Beispiele, in denen deshalb *Verantwortung* meiner Meinung nach besser passt als *Rechenschaft* (wiederum von *linguee.de*):

> Die beiden Richtlinien decken auch Fälle ab, in denen nicht die die Politik des Arbeitgebers umsetzende Einzelperson, sondern der Arbeitgeber selbst (das Unternehmen oder die Organisation) direkt für die diskriminierende Handlung zur Verantwortung gezogen werden kann. [Quelle nicht mehr online](http://humanconsultancy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/Review6-7german.pdf)
>
> Rechenschaftspflicht kann verstanden
>   werden als die rechtliche und politische
>   Verpflichtung einer unabhängigen Zentralbank, ihre Entscheidungen vor den
>   Bürgern und Bürgerinnen und deren
>   gewählten Vertretern ausführlich zu erläutern und zu rechtfertigen, sodass
>   diese die Zentralbank für die Erfüllung
>   ihrer Aufgaben zur Verantwortung ziehen können. [Quelle](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/other/geldpolitik2004de.pdf)
>
> Der Kongress der Abgeordneten kann durch einen mit absoluter Mehrheit angenommenen
>   Misstrauensantrag die Regierung politisch zur Verantwortung ziehen. *boe.gob.es, genaue Quelle nicht verlinkt*
>
> Strafrechtlich nicht zur Verantwortung ziehen liess sich bislang dagegen der Bestochene. [Quelle](http://www.swlegal.ch/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?disposition=attachment&nodeguid=b3be003d-899a-46bd-b806-03f486067723)

Wie gesagt, das sind Nuancen. Oft kann man davon ausgehen, dass *Rechenschaft ablegen* dazu führen wird, dass *verantwortlich sein* festgestellt wird, weshalb in vielen Fällen beide Wendungen gegeneinander austauschbar sind.

Comment: Diese Handlung oder dieses Ereignis werden als Tatsache angenommen; es geht nicht darum, diese noch zu diskutieren. Gute Beobachtung. Klingt richtig!

Answer (score 1):

I use them interchangeably, my friends use them interchangeably and it would feel like getting  a present if someone could point to a slight difference in meaning (except something juristic, that's too technical for me) :)